# Searching dateoptionaltime field in elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to query a row based on a date field in elasticsearch (not the range), using the lucene syntax but not getting the expected response, 
I checked the mapping using _mapping it gives me the following result for the index, for the field ordered at:

```
ordered_at: {
type: "date",
format: "dateOptionalTime" 
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#date-math

and

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateOptionalTimeParser()

suggests that the following format should be acceptable yyyy-mm-dd (2015-01-03).

Following are some of the formats i have tried to fetch the result:

```
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"2015\-01\-03"
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015\-01\-03*
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015-01-03
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:[2015\-01\-03 TO 15\-01\-20]
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:[2015-01-03 TO 15-01-20]
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:[20150103 TO 150120]
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:01/03/2015
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"20150103"
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:20150103
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"2015-01-03T18:53:37.000Z" (this does work but i need to just submit date and not time)
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"2015-01-03"
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"2015-01-03*"
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015-01-03*
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015/01/03
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015\01\03
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015-01-03
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015\-01\-03   
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015-01-03*
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015/-01/-03
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"2015-03-01"
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:2015/03/01
_search?pretty=true&q=ordered_at:"2015-01-03"*
```

Following is a sample of how the data is displayed when we query by other fields:

```
ordered_at: [
"2015-01-03T18:53:37.000Z"
]
```

No idea what am i missing, any clue? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `q=date:[2015-01-03 TO 2015-01-20]`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, tried but doesn`t seems to work, gives random result ordered_at: "2014-10-09T16:04:38.000Z".

Comment: @Sirius hm, my tests were really simple. Can you provide some test data that fails and some that does return what it should?